# Fan runs at 100% [Linux & Windows]

Tags: linux, cpu, fan, temperature

I've got an Asus Laptop X550JK, for some reason, when I try to install programs or updates, I notice the Fan runs at 100% (**2800 RPM**) and makes noise.

with `sensors` command, I get this in IDLE mode (no program or updates installing)

[image]

Sometimes, the fan becomes quiet and doesn't make any noise although during working, that makes me confused.

A month ago, I tried to clean the Fan and change the thermal paste of the CPU, but this issue still present.

CPU & RAM usage :

[image]

BIOS version :

[image]

Can anyone helps me to get resolve this issue

Comment: How is your CPU/RAM consumption? It can be thermal throttling.

Comment: @CaldeiraG thank you for your comment, can please check my question again, I've added a screenshot of System Monitor

Comment: Has this always occurred?  If so, it could be a UEFI firmware issue.  If it hasn't, do you recall what change was made that effectuated the speed change?  Have you tried updating to the [most recent](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/X550JK/HelpDesk_BIOS/) UEFI version

Comment: @JW0914 thank you for your comment, yes I've updated the BIOS from the link you gives me, the issue always happens, I've tried with Linux (Ubuntu, Minit & Deepin distros) as well as Windows 7 & 10

Comment: Did the issue begin after updating the UEFI firmware (the firmware isn't BIOS)?  If so, try downgrading to the previous UEFI firmware version from ASUS' site

Comment: @JW0914 I have faced this issue before and after updating the BIOS,I've downloaded the BIOS file from [HERE](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/X550JK/HelpDesk_BIOS/)

Comment: You're skipping over the original question: _do you recall what change was made that effectuated the speed change_.  Since this happened before, do you recall what change occurred then or any similarities between before and now?  Have you booted into the UEFI firmware to adjust the fan values (if the firmware makes them available, some do and some don't)

Comment: @JW0914,I haven't changed anything, to be sure, I tried with different OS, also I've updated the BIOS and restore all settings to default,I've clean the Fan from dust and change thermal paste of the CPU & GPU